# rviz doesn't visualize the Markers

Tags: ros, rviz, markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !
I am learning currently to use Point and Line Markers by the tutorials. And, I am confused  what it is a mistake in my code, because there were not any errors in the compilation.
My implementation should show points and line, but rviz could get the name of Fixed Frame only. The scene is empty without any markers..
The code is..

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <visualization_msgs/Marker.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ros/console.h>
#include <cmath>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "voronoi_2D_node"); 
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher voronoi_pub = n.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("visual_marker_pub", 10);
ros::Rate r(30);

while (ros::ok())
{
visualization_msgs::Marker line, point;
line.header.frame_id = point.header.frame_id = "/my_frame";
line.ns = point.ns = "voronoi_2D_node";
point.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
line.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
line.pose.orientation.w = point.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
//line.header.stamp = point.header.stamp = ros::Time();
//line.lifetime = point.lifetime = ros::Duration();

point.id = 0;
line.id = 1;

point.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::POINTS;
line.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::LINE_STRIP;

point.scale.x = 0.2;
point.scale.y = 0.2;

line.scale.x = 0.1;

point.color.g = 1.0f;
point.color.a = 1.0;


line.color.b = 1.0;
line.color.a = 1.0; 

//point.pose.position.x = 0;
//point.pose.position.y = 0;
//point.pose.position.z = 0;

//line.pose.position.x = 0;
//line.pose.position.y = 1;
//line.pose.position.z = 0;

for (uint32_t i=0; i<2; ++i)
{
geometry_msgs::Point p;
p.x = i;
p.y = 0.5;
p.z = 0.5;

line.points.push_back(p);
point.points.push_back(p);


//ROS::INFO("The coordinates: x=[%d] , y=[%d] , z=[%d]", p.x, p.y, p.z);
std::cout<<"The coordinates: "<<p<<std::endl;

}
voronoi_pub.publish(point);
voronoi_pub.publish(line);

r.sleep();
}

}
```

The output is .. (in the terminal):

```
The coordinates: x: 0
y: 0.5
z: 0.5

The coordinates: x: 1
y: 0.5
z: 0.5
```

Do you know what kind of a reason can be if rviz doesn't illustrate the markers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225103/rviz-doesn%27t-visualize-the-markers/) by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2016-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Everything looked good to me. So I just tested your code and the markers popped up in `rviz` no problem. I'm guessing that your problem is most likely related to the Fixed Frame in rviz. If you are only running your node and rviz, then there are no nodes publishing on the `/tf` topic (via a tf broadcaster). Thus rviz has no way of knowing what frames are available. Try manually typing `my_frame` in for the Fixed Frame in rviz, and I'm guessing your markers will show up.

To see that this is the issue, try starting a static transform publisher. Then rviz will be able to correctly select a fixed frame. E.g.:

```
rosrun tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 world my_frame
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on 2016-01-26**:
Jarvis, I ran the static tf too ... But, there are no any markers in rviz.
Thank you for testing my code. Now, I know that it works )

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-01-26**:
Did you add the markers on the correct topic (`/visual_marker_pub`) to the display?

**Comment by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on 2016-01-27**:
That's right! I didnt add the Market Topic )) By default, there was `/visualization_marker`. When I clicked twice on the dropdownlist, my topic's name ( `/visual_marker_pub` ) popped up ))
Thank you, Jarvis

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case, the above-mentioned solutions do not work, just check whether you have selected the right frame-id on the screen of rviz. This was the error that I also faced, you will have to change it to the frame id that you have mentioned while creating markers. By default, I think it is set to /map.

---

Originally posted by [Sarthak](https://answers.ros.org/users/33584/sarthak/) with karma: 21 on 2018-02-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on 2018-02-09**:
Thank u for ur contribution :)